# Making a gradient in FXRuby

Tags: ruby, fxruby

Is there a way to create a gradient in FXRuby? If so, how would I implement it?

I have tried looking at https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fxruby/Fox/FXImage and it didn't make much sense to me, If I could get elaboration on what `#gradient` means and how to use it, that would be great.

Comment: [`#gradient`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fxruby/Fox/FXImage#gradient-instance_method) is an instance method of class `FXImage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fxruby/Fox/FXImage#gradient-instance_method) here's how you would use the method, but first you'll need to install and require the gem

```
gem install fxruby
```

Then in your code:

```
require 'fxruby'

# the arguments represent rgb colors:
# #gradient(topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright)
```

You'll need to pass the RGB colors you want to use for the actual gradient but here's an example of the syntax

```
FXImage.gradient(
  Fox.FXRGB(253, 245, 230), 
  Fox.FXRGB(253, 245, 230), 
  Fox.FXRGB(253, 245, 230), 
  Fox.FXRGB(253, 245, 230)
)
```

See here for [examples of colors](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fxruby/Fox/FXColor)

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Thank you so much